# Smallest Possible Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

Smallest Possible Integer

> Given an integer N, print the smallest possible integer that can be
> formed using all the digits of N.
>
> Boundary Condition: 1<= N <= 9999999999
>
> Input Format: The first line contains N.
>
> Output Format: The first line contains the smallest possible integer
> that can be formed using all the digits of N.

```
Sample Input/Output 1:
Input:
45223

Output:
22345

Sample Input/Output 2:
Input:
48903012

Output:
10023489
```

My code-

```
a=input()
c={}

for i in a:
    if i in c:
        c[i]+=1
    else:
        c[i]=1

v=dict(sorted(c.items()))
k=list(v.keys())
u=list(v.values())

if k[0]=='0':
    m={k[1]:u[1],k[0]:u[0]}
    for i,j in v.items():
        if i not in k[:2]:
            m[i]=j


    for i in m:
        print(i*m[i],end='')
else:

    for i in v:
        print(i*v[i],end='')
```

5 test cases passed out of 7 test cases.
cant figure out why other 2 test cases failed as its being locked.

Comment: Can you describe your strategy.  The solution should be to sort the digits and move the smallest non-zero digit to the first position.  Your could seems to have a lot more logic than would be needed to do just that.

Comment: 12 has 2 digits 1002 4 digits here every digit should involve in giving a meaningful smallest possible integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need dictionaries or loops for this.  Sort the digits and move the first non-zero digit to the first position:

```
n = input()                     # n is a string
s = sorted(n)                   # sorted list of digits
i = s.count('0')                # position of 1st non-zero
s.insert(0,s.pop(i))            # move it to 1st position
print(*s,sep="")                # final number
```